# Allow one flex item to wrap to multiple lines

Tags: css, flexbox

I have HTML that I cannot change that is similar to the below. I need to use Flexbox to re-order the elements (and force a 'line break' before the last item). How can I make it so that most of the flex items are treated as atomic units, but that one in particular—`#c` in this example—is allowed to start on the same line as the previous item and then word wrap like a standard `display:inline` element?

```css
section {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 450px;
   background:orange;
   padding:0.2em;
}
span {
   background:yellow;
   padding:2px 4px;
   border-radius:3px;
   border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,50%);
   margin:0 3px;
}
#a { order:1 }
#b { order:2 }
#c {
   order:3;
   background:none;
   border:none;
}
section::before {
   content:'';
   order:4;
   width:100%;
}
#d { order:5 }
```

```html
<section>
<span id="c">with an earthquake, birds and snakes and aeroplanes, and Lenny Bruce is not afraid</span>
<span id="a">That's great</span>
<span id="b">it starts</span>
<span id="d">— R.E.M.</span>
</section>
```

To be extra clear, in the above example I want "That's great it starts with an earthquake" to all be on the same line, but then the text wraps to the next line, and finally "— R.E.M." is forced onto its own line.

Comment: You can't. That's not possible with flexbox. Flex children cannot wrap like that.

Comment: Do you want the lyrics to wrap naturally or do you want a specific break after "earthquake"?

Comment: @JonP To flow naturally, as though those lyrics were display inline.

Comment: @Phrogz Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only approximate it using some hacks. There is probably no generic solution

```css
section {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 450px;
   background:orange;
   padding:0.2em;
}
span {
   background:yellow;
   padding:2px 4px;
   border-radius:3px;
   border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,50%);
   margin:0 3px;
}
#a { order:1 }
#b { order:2 }
#c {
   order:3;
   background:none;
   border:none;
   /* added this*/
    margin-top: -1.2em;
    text-indent: 148px;
    /**/
}

section::before {
   content:'';
   order:4;
   width:100%;
}
#d { order:5 }
```

```html
<section>
<span id="c">with an earthquake, birds and snakes and aeroplanes, and Lenny Bruce is not afraid</span>
<span id="a">That's great</span>
<span id="b">it starts</span>
<span id="d">— R.E.M.</span>
</section>
```

Comment: An ingenious hack, that would almost work for my needs if the contents of `#a` and `#b` had fixed widths.

Answer (score -2):

try changing your css (section) to:

```
section {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: fit-content;
   background:orange;
   padding:0.2em;
}
```